# Чем лучше пользоваться для отправки почты, вложений с linux?

Tags: linux, bash, debian, centos, sendmail

Интересуют в основном ОС Centos и Debian. Сейчас используется sendmail, но вот на одной из ОС он не был обнаружен. Есть ли решение работающее из коробки на последних версиях этих дистрибутивов? Если нет, то что лучше использовать? С тем же sendmail сейчас столкнулся с проблемой отправки вложений. Их можно как-то отправлять с sendmail? Или если нет, то чем заменить лучше?

Comment: Используйте `smtp`.

Comment: программа sendmail — это mta (mail transfer agent). среди функций mta **вообще** нет ни «отправки почты», ни, тем более, каких-то там «вложений». то, о чём вы упоминаете, относится к функциям mua (mail user agent). // вопрос, конечно, в данном виде, подлежит закрытию по двум причинам: 1. звучит бредово: функции mua приписаны mta. 2. «у меня чего-то тут не получается, посоветуйте программу, чтобы получилось».

Comment: в sendmail `-a attachmentFile`

Comment: @PotroNik, вот объясните, откуда вы это берёте?

Comment: @0andriy из памяти, да, действительно, перепутал его с sendEmail, помнил что на сервере раньше почту так отправляли, ошибся.

Comment: В пакете `sharutils` есть утилита `uuencode`. С ее помощью, а также с помощью утилиты `mail` (`mailx`) можно отправить письмо с вложением: `uuencode file.txt file.txt | mail admin@google.com`. Где `file.txt` - файл, который надо отправить аттачем к письму.

Comment: Если просто надо отправить почтой файл с командной строки, то довольно удобен `mpack`. uuencode, как посоветовал @de_frag, тоже работает и несколько более стандартен, но немного больше добавляет к объёмы пересылаемых данных за счёт другого кодирования.

Answer (score 0):

В [этом](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17359/1597497) вопросе дано множество ответов по данной теме. Приведу компиляцию из вариантов:

```
$ echo "This is the message body" | mutt -a "/path/to/file.to.attach" -s "subject of message" -- recipient@domain.com
$ gzip -c mysqldbbackup.sql | uuencode mysqldbbackup.sql.gz  | mail -s "MySQL DB" backup@email.com
$ echo "This is the message body" | mutt -a file.to.attach -s "subject of message" recipient@domain.com
$ mail -s "Backup" -a mysqldbbackup.sql backup@email.com < message.txt
$ cat message.txt | mail -s "Backup" -a mysqldbbackup.sql backup@email.com 
$ sendemail -f sender@some.where -t receiver@some.place -m "Here are your files!" -a file1.jpg file2.zip
$ echo 'These are contents of my mail' | mailx -s 'This is my email subject' -a /path/to/attachment_file.log email_id@example.com
```